# Devise + Rails 4: customizing location and formatting of flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have a `User` model that is working in conjunction with Devise, and upon sign-in, for instance, I get the following flash message:

[image]

How would I customize this so that, for instance, the text is centered, or the flash bar is higher up (closer to the navbar?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Devise merely adds the message to flash. On redirection by Devise upon any request, the flash message is displayed by your application. Check your layout and in particular application.html.haml for code like

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  %p= msg
```

or something similar where flash is being iterated. Once you find that, you can add the appropriate id or class to the element and write CSS to style it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use firebug/chrome's developer tool to check the styles applied to the flash message (right click on your element and select inspect element). Then I would find out where the css file is and override the style from there.